# Private NPM Registry behind proxy on a different path

Tags: nginx, npm, nexus

I have got a private Sonar Nexus NPM registry behind a Nginx reverse proxy. The registry itself (i.e. without the proxy) is hosted under `http://localhost:8081/repository/npm`. The proxy is set up in such a way that it provides access through the `http://npm.devserver` (see Nginx config below).

The problem is, that `npm install` fails when downloading a packages `.tgz` file. For example, when trying to install React, NPM fails with

```
400 Bad Request - GET http://npm.devserver/repository/npm/react/-/react-17.0.2.tgz
```

As you can see, npm added `/repository/npm` to the path (which is required when accessing the registry directly but not when accessing it through the proxy).

Is there some way to avoid this problem? I know that setting up a second location (with the path `/repository/npm`) in the proxy works, but this does not seem like a clean solution; I would rather set up Nexus in such a way that it tells NPM to download with the correct path straight away.

My current Nginx setup looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name npm.devserver;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/repository/npm/;

                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Reapl-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_connect_timeout   150;
                proxy_send_timeout      100;
                proxy_read_timeout      100;
                proxy_buffers           4 32k;
                client_max_body_size    500m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not currently possible:  https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10644